# How to correctly include ".razor" file to NuGet package?

Tags: c#, razor, nuget

As you can see in the picture below, my NuGet package has the normal C# classes, partial C# classes merged with razor files (below **Components** directory) and Single File Components (**SVG_Icons** directory).

[image]

As default below directories will be included to NuGet package:

- Components
- Exceptions
- Helpers

However, the **SVG_Icons** will not be (while it included only Single File Components).
However just to specify

```cs
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="SVG_Icons/**/*.razor" />
</ItemGroup>
```

is not enough because, looks like, the C# will try to compile the `.razor` files as plain `.cs` files. What else I have to do?

Here is the example file of the SVG Icon:

```cs
@using YamatoDaiwa.Frontend.Components.Abstractions


@implements ISupportsFlexibleExternalCSS_ClassesSpecifyingForRootElement


<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  viewBox="0 0 20 20"
  class=@(((ISupportsFlexibleExternalCSS_ClassesSpecifyingForRootElement)this).rootElementSpaceSeparatedExternalCSS_Classes)
>
  <path d="M10 0a10 10 0 1010 10A10 10 0 0010 0zM8.47 14.74l-.09-.09-4.05-4.05 1.22-1.23 2.92 2.91 5.89-5.9 1.23 1.23z"></path>    
</svg>


@code {

  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public string? rootElementModifierCSS_Class { get; set; } = null;

  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public string[]? rootElementModifierCSS_Classes { get; set; } = null;

  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public string? rootElementSpaceSeparatedModifierCSS_Classes { get; set; } = null;

}
```

Comment: Can you share what is in one of those SVG_Icons/**/*.razor files?

Comment: @theCuriousOne Sure. I have added the example of SVG Icon component to the end of the question field.

Comment: Usually source files are not included in Nuget packages. When they are they are included in contentFiles. In your picture you are showing a file tree with all the source in it. Is this a view of part of the internal contents of the package?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this at the specific file level is to:

1. Click on the file in Solution Explorer
2. In the Properties Window, set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer" (or possibly, "Copy always")

Next time you build, files with this setting should end up in the output folder.

Alternatively, you can set up a Post-build event to copy all files in the SVG_Icons folder (and optionally subfolders) to $(OutDir)

Answer (score 1):

- Add the ".razor" files to your project.
- Set the **build action** of the ".razor" files to **Content**.
- Build the NuGet package project.